# Read two lines at a time from a .txt file - C++ getline/ streams?

Tags: c++, string, file, stream, getline

I am using the below code to read a file, search for the given string and display that line. But I want to read the `immediate next line` to what I've found in string search of the file. I can increment the line number to get the next line, but do I need to use `getline` again on the file?

Here is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

    int main()
    {
        std::ifstream file( "data.txt" ) ;
        std::string search_str = "Man" ;
        std::string line ;
        int line_number = 0 ;
        while( std::getline( file, line ) )
        {
            ++line_number ;

            if( line.find(search_str) != std::string::npos )
            {
                std::cout << "line " << line_number << ": " << line << '\n' ;
                std::cout << ++line_number; // read the next line too
            }

        }

        return (0);
    }
```

Here is the contents of my file:

```
Stu
Phil and Doug
Jason
Bourne or X
Stephen
Hawlkings or Jonathan
Major
League or Justice
Man
Super or Bat
```

Comment: I'm not certain what u want. Do you want to display the next line after the match only or the matching line and the next line?

Comment: Yes Troy, the matching line and immediate next line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need the `getline` function to read the next line.

```
    while( file && std::getline( file, line ) )
    {
        ++line_number ;

        if( line.find(search_str) != std::string::npos )
        {
            std::cout << "line " << line_number << ": " << line << '\n' ;
            std::cout << ++line_number; // read the next line too
            std::getline(file, line);  // then do whatever you want.

        }

    }
```

please note the usage of `file` in the while clause, which is important. istream object could be evaluated to boolean which is equivalent to file.good(). The reason that you want to check the state is the second `getline()` function may reach the end the of file and throws an exception. You can also add the check after the second `getline` call and add a `break` if `!file.good()`.

```
std::getline(file, line);  // then do whatever you want.
if(line.good()){
   // line is read stored correctly and you can use it
}
else{
  // you are at end of the file and line is not read
  break;
}
```

then the check won't be necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are accidentally reusing the same variable name, but `file` as both the input stream and a boolean flag is either incorrect (as the names conflict) or unnecessary (as getline returns the `ostream&`).  He can get away with simply setting a boolean flag when he finds a result, and in the next loop (after reading the line), test for it and break out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need another `std::getline` call, but you will need a flag to avoid it:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file( "data.txt" ) ;
    std::string search_str = "Man" ;
    std::string line ;
    int line_number = 0 ;
    bool test = false;
    while(std::getline(file, line))
    {
        ++line_number;
        if (test)
        {
            std::cout << "line " << line_number << ": " << line << '\n' ;
            break;
        }

        if( line.find(search_str) != std::string::npos )
        {
            std::cout << "line " << line_number << ": " << line << '\n' ;
            test = true;
        }

    }

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `bool` flag variable that you set when u find a match, then loop again after finding your match so that you can get the next line. Test the flag to determine whether you've found a match in the previous loop or not.

Comment: You really should try figure these sorts of things out for yourself after getting some guidance. You won't learn anything otherwise: See here anyway: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4b080eec491313a

Comment: Hey troy, I am using following code as said by Zac, is this right one or any memory leak or any mistake is there? - please check here: http://ideone.com/V2E4g3